# Baire: Equivalent Statements II

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, baire-category

Moreover, why does it follow for Baire Spaces and why is it strictly weaker that:

- $X=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\quad\Rightarrow\quad\exists k_0\in\mathbb{N},x_0\in X: A_{k_0}\in\mathcal{N}_{x_0}$

*...in words, the space is not meagre iff whenever it is a given by a countable union of subsets then at least one of them is large.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Turning my comment at your other question into an answer*

If a Baire space $B$ is the union of countably many sets, then at least one of them has a closure with non-
empty interior. But its own interior could still be empty. Take for example $$\Bbb R=\Bbb R∖\Bbb Q∪⋃\{\{q\}∣q∈\Bbb Q\}$$
 The set of irrationals as well as each singleton $\{q\}$ has empty interior.